# Show Music Player On Bottom of Every View of flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am new to flutter and I need to know, how can I show the music player on every view of the flutter app. Can you please guide me to do that, as I am using the bottom sheet in a flutter, and seems like it's not fit my purpose.

[image]

Here I need to add only the bottom widget which showing the music playing.

Comment: use miniplayer (https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer)

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to use a `bottomNavigationBar` in your global `Scaffold`.

And in your `body`, you will have to create a new navigation stack in order for the navigation to change only the body (not replacing the whole `Scaffold`).

It would look like this:

```
class MusicApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: PlayerBottomBar(), // this is where you put your player bar
      body: Navigator(
        onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              // todo return a screen... ,
            },
            settings: settings,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you manage to achieved this. I also need to implement same music player need to show on bottom of all screens.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one I have used in my music app. one of the most straightforward solutions is to wrap widgets in columns in the bottom bar of the app at the root level.

```
return Scaffold(
    body: tabs[currentTabIndex],
    backgroundColor: ColorConstants.kBackGround,
    bottomNavigationBar: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          width: 100.w,
          height: 60,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.black38,
          child: Text(
            "Mini Player",
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: currentTabIndex,
          elevation: 0,
          onTap: (currentIndex) => setState(() {
            currentTabIndex = currentIndex;
          }),
          selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          selectedItemColor: ColorConstants.kDarkFontColor,
          backgroundColor: ColorConstants.kBackGround,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: ""),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: ""),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.library_books), label: "")
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
```

> also you can checkout this video for the open and close mini player when the song start [youtube](https://youtu.be/A3YOz5XFE_8)

[image]